# Android - FTP Display image in ImageView without storing the image in SD

Tags: android, ftp

Stocked, since backend developer stored images in FTP server and i need to display these images in ImageView without saving it to SD card.

is it possible to just retrieve the image(jpg/png) and convert it to Bitmap and display it directly to ImageView without having to save it.

I'm searching a lot but all technics used saving to SD card way.

Comment: if you have the direct URL to the file then you can load the image to the ImageView from URI

Comment: Yes, i have direct URL to the image, please i need more help as the blow code didn't work with me.. Image still not appear.

Comment: Add Breakpoints and Log the values of your variables. The code below should work, it worked for me. **UNLESS YOU HAVE SOME AUTHENTICATION required for your FTP**

Answer (score -1):

```
    public class async extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Bitmap> {

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... strings) {
        public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(src);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.connect();
                InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                return myBitmap;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Log exception
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        if(result != null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(result)
    }
}
```